# Getting the third point from two points on one line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

My question is the following

[image]

How can I get point $(x_3, y_3)$  from points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ ?

The distance of point $(x_3, y_3)$ from $(x_1, y_1)$ is $300$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> > **Assume:**
> >     $$dx = x2 - x1$$
> >     $$dy = y2 - y1$$

---

> > **Then,**
> >     $$x3 = x1 + dx*k$$
> >     $$y3 = y1 + dy*k$$

---

The square of distance between $p1$ and $p3$ is:

$$(dx^2 + dy^2)*k^2 = 300^2$$

Now you can find $k$ and then $x3$ and $y3$

Comment: It gives me wrong answer

Comment: @Sami Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry its right. It was only my programming language problem. It tired it in javascript. I later came to know that there i had to use `Math.pow(x,2)` instead of `x^2`

Answer (score 0):

defining:

```
P1 (x1,y1)
```

and

```
P2 (x2,y2)
```

and the distance "d", in the case with the value of 300 units

```
d = 300
```

you can define a vector (namely "u") pointing from P1 to P2, using vector subtraction:

```
u = P2 - P1
```

(in the way that P2 = P1 + u)

then, you can normalize "u" making it unit norm, we can name that vector "v"

```
v(ux/norm(u),uy/norm(u))
```

with

```
norm(u) = (ux^2+uy^2)^0.5
```

to obtain the third point (namely P3), you need just to sum a vector with the direction from P1 to P2 with the norm equal to the distance (in case 300 units), in our notation:

```
P3 = P1 + v * d
```

Thanks to the illustration, we now that the direction is from P1 to P2. But remember, that only given the distance, are two solutions: the above and with -v  (300 units from P1 in the direction from P2 to P1).

That solution is valid for a euclidean space with any number of dimensions (changes only the number of components to normalize and the number of elements to calculate the norm).